# geom_jitter() and nearPoint issue for geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is it possible to select points using nearPoints() generated by geom_jitter() for a boxplot? I'm constructing a shiny app where I can select a data point to return a table (renderable), but whenever I try to click points outside of the vertical line, it doesn't seem to register. However, it seems to work fine for geom_point() when all of the points are condensed on the vertical line. Some incomplete pseudocode is attached. [image]

```
celldistUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput(ns("plot_abs"), click = ns("plot_click")), tableOutput(ns("data"))
  )
}

output$plot_rel <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data, aes(x = exposure_time, y = cell_type)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(color = exposure_time)) + 
    geom_jitter(aes(color = exposure_time)) 
})
      
output$data <- renderTable({
 req(input$plot_click)
    nearPoints(data, input$plot_click, xvar = "exposure_time")
```

Comment: A workaround is to do the jitter manually.